# Using generated image as link to be used in forums?

Tags: php

I came across php image functions and I've successfully managed to create signature with php now after generating how to let users to use the generated image as link on their signatures or w/e?

```
 <?php
    $dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');
    $src = imagecreatefrompng('blade_02.png');

    imagealphablending($dest, false);
    imagesavealpha($dest, true);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($src, 0, 0, 0); 
    imagecolortransparent($src, $black);
    imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 17, 13, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0);
    imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 168, 70, 0, 0, 60, 100, 100);
    $font_black = imagecolorallocate($dest, 2, 1, 8);
    imagestring($dest, 3,357,19, "118" , $font_black);

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($dest);

    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);

    ?>
```

html

```
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:150px; LEFT:500px;" SRC="style/inventoryclean.png">
<!--Weapon begin-->
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:163px; LEFT:512px;" SRC="<?php  echo $wep_icon; ?>" onmouseover="TagToTip('Span2')">
<span id="Span2"><?php echo $seal_type[0]; ?><br><br> <?php echo $seal_wep; ?><br><br><?php echo $Degree_wep; ?> <br></span> 
<!--Wepaon end-->
```

Comment: This question is too unclear. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the image to a file, simply give them the link to that file.

If you are saving the data used to generate the image in a DB, give them a link to the file that'll build the image, appending the query string on the end that you use to pull the data out of the database.

**EDIT**

From the code you have provided, you appear to create the image, and then destroy the files. Try this:

```
imagepng($dest, 'the_new_file.png');
```

This will save the file to the filesystem instead of just showing it to the screen
You can see more about imagepng and it's options here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

Comment: Well how to save the image to a file then upon generating ?

Comment: Thanks now I've another question what If I'm using html to generate images is it possible to save it too ? I attached the code at the main post again I want to save the image including all the images written over it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, HTML so save an image? Also that extra code you posted is a little pointless when it's just a few variables.

Comment: Actually it's not pointless since it retrieves some variables from database , view image and write those variables over it.So is it possible to save such image via html  ?

Comment: Yes, but you posted it out of context - so it's no help. And yes, I know html. You asked about saving an image with HTML, you can't. A *user* can save it when presented on the page, or *you* can save it with PHP. You need to be clearer with what you are asking me.

Comment: Well as my first question it's done already and now I'm asking my 2nd question after writing variables / putting images over it how it's possible to save the image including what was written over via php or html ?.If it's not possible with html then how to save it with php with all variables / images over it ? Thanks again for your time

Comment: It'd be better to create a new question rather than tagging it onto this one